# Probability Distributions: Convergence of N = 30 vs Infinity

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence

In Probability and Statistics, we are taught the following facts:

- "Central Limit Theorem" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) tells us that the Expected Value of ANY Random Variable converges to a (Standard) Normal Distribution as the sample size tends to infinity. This theorem greatly facilitates statistical inferences.
- We are also told an "informal rule of thumb" : When the sample size is greater than 30 (n > 30), we can begin to take advantage of the Central Limit Theorem.

I have been trying to learn more about the mathematical validity of this "rule of thumb".

Here are my thoughts:

- Although the Expectation of ALL Random Variables converges to a (standard) Normal Distribution as the sample size tends to infinity - **is it possible that the Expectation of some Random Variables might tend to require larger sample sizes to exhibit the same convergence properties?**
- As an example - **perhaps Random Variables corresponding to Multivariate Irregular/Multi-Modal Probability Distributions (e.g. high dimensional mixture distributions) might require larger sample sizes for the Central Limit Theorem to apply compared to simpler Univariate Probability Distributions?**
- And finally : I wonder **how "dangerous" it might be to assume that the sample size is large enough for the Central Limit theorem to apply and perform statistical inferences on a (standard) Normal Distribution - when in fact the sample size was not large enough for the Central Limit Theorem to apply?** Is it known that to what extent this can invalidate statistical inferences?

Thanks!

Note: I think this might be one of the advantages of Bayesian Statistics. For infinite sample sizes, the Central Limit Theorem applies - however, for finite sample sizes, the sampling distribution for the "parameter of interest" might better follow some other probability distribution ... and we might be able to create a "Bayesian Posterior Distribution" that better models the distribution of this parameter under finite sample sizes and as a result provide more realistic inferences.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2541/what-references-should-be-cited-to-support-using-30-as-a-large-enough-sample-siz

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry–Esseen_theorem

Comment: @ Andrew Zhang : thank you for this link! How is Berry-Esseen theorem different from the Central Limit Theorem?